# Search multiple fields using Surround Query Parser?

Tags: search, solr, lucene, solrcloud, surround

I have a the following surround query searching in the solr field content.

```
 _query_:"{!surround maxBasicQueries=10000} content:5N(tru*,(equi* OR and*))
```

How do I submit a query which is ORed or ANDed with multiple fields. 
Is something like this possible with Surround QueryParser? where I can search two fields simultaneously.

*query*:"{!surround maxBasicQueries=10000} AND (content:5N(tru*,(equi* OR and*)),examples:10N(em*,rit*))

Comment: What do you mean by that? Something like `5N(content:tru*,(content:equi* OR otherfield:and*))` doesn't make any sense (can't be within five words if it's in an entirely different field), so what are you looking for?

Comment: @femtoRgon updated the question with a detailed example, Its basically my need to search multiple fields in one surround query

Answer (score 1):

You could just issue two surround queries, one for each field. Then, you could combine them as you like. Remember you can [split parts of queries into separate variables](https://home.apache.org/~hossman/rev2016/#/start) to make them easier to manage.

Also, you seem to be using wildcards to do prefix queries. You may want to look into using [EdgeNGrams filter](http://www.solr-start.com/info/analyzers/#EdgeNGramFilterFactory) instead in the indexing phase. It makes your index large, but the searches faster.